# How do you say "I am stuck with step X"? 進まない

Tags: word-requests

I am wondering how you can state that you are stuck on a specific step of a task.
Can you say it this way.

> すみません。事前の設置手順のステップ４(git クローン)を進めないで、手伝っていただけないでしょうか？

Is the 進まない the proper word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using the verb [行]{ゆ/い}き[詰]{づ}まる, as in:

> 「ステップ４で**行き詰まって**しまいました。」
>   「ステップ４で**行き詰まって**しまったので、手伝っていただけないでしょうか。」

Answer (score 1):

I think ステップ4に困ってて works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> ステップ4(git クローン)から進めない

is probably what you want.

By the way, 進めないで means `don't advance forward`. I imagine that's not what you want to say. Maybe you meant 進めない**の**で?